# query where at least one of two fields falls into date range (

Tags: axapta, x++

I've got a query that runs on a view that contains two modifiedBy dates. I need to return all records where either of these dates falls into a specified range.

From everything I've researched it seems I need something like this:

```
    qbdsCustTableAddressView
        .addRange(fieldNum(TCMCustTableAddressView, CustTableModified))
        .value(
            strFmt("(%1>='%2' AND %1<='%3') || (%4>='%2' AND %4<='%3')",
                fieldstr(TCMCustTableAddressView, CustTableModified),
                DateTimeUtil::toStr(contract.parmFromDateTime()),
                DateTimeUtil::toStr(contract.parmToDateTime()),
                fieldstr(TCMCustTableAddressView, EBillModified),
                0
            )
        );
```

when I compare the resulting query to what is produced by:

```
qbdsCustTableAddressView
    .addRange(fieldNum(TCMCustTableAddressView, CustTableModified))
    .value(strFmt("%1..%2", contract.parmFromDateTime(), contract.parmtoDateTime()));
```

Then the above *looks* correct by I'm getting a non-specific "Syntax error near 22"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with the parenthesis, single quotation marks and using `AND` instead of `&&`.

This should work:

```
qbdsCustTableAddressView
    .addRange(fieldNum(TCMCustTableAddressView, CustTableModified))
    .value(
        strFmt("(((%1 >= %2) && (%1 <= %3)) || ((%4 >= %2) && (%4 <= %3)))",
            fieldstr(TCMCustTableAddressView, CustTableModified),
            DateTimeUtil::toStr(contract.parmFromDateTime()),
            DateTimeUtil::toStr(contract.parmToDateTime()),
            fieldstr(TCMCustTableAddressView, EBillModified),
            0
        )
    );
```

Comment: The query expression must always be surrounded by a set of ()

Comment: @Jan, I presumed so too but I tested my code before posting with and without outer () and it worked in both cases do I opted for the smaller piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
qbdsCustTableAddressView
    .addRange(fieldNum(TCMCustTableAddressView, CustTableModified))
    .value(SysQuery::range(contract.parmFromDateTime(), contract.parmtoDateTime()));
```

The difference being `SysQuery::range(<from>, <to>)`

I don't see an obvious problem, but perhaps that might flush it out for you.